# "scientists" and "social scientists"

Tags: meaning-in-context

what is the difference between "scientists" and "social scientists" here?

Context:

Are artists born? There is some evidence that scientists may be. Cambridge Professor Simon Baron-Cohen, an expert in autism, has presented data which shows that scientists score significantly higher on a standard scoring test for autistic tendencies than either humanities scholars or social scientists.

Comment: The writer didn't think to use the term "natural scientists" (or, better in the above context, something like "scholars of natural science").

Answer (score 1):

A "social scientist" is one who studies social phenomena, like psychology, economics, history, or politics. These things are generally difficult to study, since it's often very difficult to set up a perfectly repeatable experiment with proper control. This is in contrast to "natural sciences" or "hard sciences", which include chemistry, physics, biology, and others. These generally deal with very precise phenomena that can be replicated much more easily in a laboratory.

Both are scientists. The social scientists probably wouldn't be very happy that this article doesn't consider them as such.

Answer (score 0):

A social scientist is a scientist who specializes in a social science such as psychology, economics, or political science.

But a scientist is a person who studies the natural sciences (like physics, chemistry and biology).

Comment: Tell that to a social scientist.